# In DDD, are repositories the only type of classes which can touch persistence?

Tags: repository, domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

In DDD, aggregate roots are persisted via repositories. But are repositories the only classes that can touch persistence in a bounded context?

I am using CQRS along side DDD. In the query side, things like view count, upvotes, these things need to be persisted but I feel it is awkward to model them as aggregate roots. I am limiting DDD aggregate root modeling to the command side. The query side is not allowed to use repositories. But often query side asks for small amount of persistence capabilities.

Also, I am using domain events, certain domain events also need to be persisted. I need something called event storage, but I only heard such terms appear in event sourcing (ES) and I am not using ES.

If such persistent classes are indeed needed. How do I call them, which layer should they belong to?

[Update]

When I read answers below, I realized my question is a bit ambiguous. **By touch, I mainly mean write** (and also including read).

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you need to be pragmatic and not dogmatic. If you need to save events, you save events. You need no repository though since repositories are only for aggregates. You can despatch your events into a message bus and persist them in some separate process. But indeed queries are queries, they cannot save anything by default except if you want to log something there. Queries are idempotent, they don't change state and have no side effects.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev I understand what you said about saving events. Also I understand that queries should not change states. But what about things that change states but awkward to model them as values objects in an aggregate root, say view counts and upvotes?

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev Probably such statistics-related things should be in a separate bounded context? In that case, I can use a simpler architecture (i.e. transaction script) to manage upvotes and view counts.

Comment: It is hard to say anything without being able to see what your domains are. If you take SO, upvotes are important attributes of questions and answers. What do you have - I don't know. If you feel it is awkward to keep them as part of your aggregate, may be they should be taken out.

Answer (score 3):

> In the query side, things like view count, upvotes, these things need
>   to be persisted

Not necessarily. CQRS doesn't specify

- whether the read model should be materialized in its own database
- how the read model is updated

The simplest CQRS implementation is one where the query side and command side use the same tables. The persistent source for Read Models could also be SQL (materialized) views based on these tables. If you do have a separate database for reads, it can be kept up-to-date by additional Command Handlers or sub-handlers or Event Handlers that operate after the command has been executed.

You can see a minimalist - yet perfectly CQRS compliant - implementation here : https://github.com/gregoryyoung/m-r/tree/master/SimpleCQRS

> But are repositories the only classes that can touch persistence in a
>   bounded context?

No, in a CQRS context, Read Model Facades (a.k.a. read side repos) can also read from it and your read model update mechanism write to it.

> Also, I am using domain events, certain domain events also need to be
>   persisted. I need something called event storage, but I only heard
>   such terms appear in event sourcing (ES) and I am not using ES.

Event stores are the main storage technology of event-sourced systems. You could use them to store a few domain events on the side in a non-ES application, but they may be overkill and too complex for the task. It depends if you need all the guarantees they offer in terms of delivery, consistency, concurrency/versioning, etc. Otherwise, a regular RDBMS or NoSQL store can do the trick.

Comment: I understand that read store and write db can be separate or sharing the same db. The query side can update read storage upon receiving domain events. But I see read store (if separate) as duplicated data source. The true copy is still in the write db. But can query directly manage updates of small things like upvotes, click count (without the command side ever knowing them)?

Comment: Things like upvotes, click counts should be persisted somewhere and someone should manage them. But should it be the command side's job, in which case, only repositories can write to db; or should it be the query side's job?

Comment: No, a repository's sole purpose is to persist aggregates. It shouldn't save query side specific data. Calculation and persistence of read models should go into a dedicated query side object.

Comment: Do you mean view counts can be directly managed (both updated and read) by the query side?

Comment: If view counts (meaning the aggregated total number of views) is denormalized query-side data, of course.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to think about your object model independantly of how you will store it in the database. You're designing an object model. Forget about the database for a moment.

You're saying that you don't want view counts or upvotes to be aggregate roots. That means you want to put them in an aggregate with some other objects. One of those objects is the aggregate root.

Without knowing more about your model, it's hard to say what you could do with more details, but the basic way would be to persist the aggregate root with the corresponding repository. The repository is not only responsible of storing the aggregate root, but the entire aggregate, following the relationships.

Think about the other side, when you are using the repository to retrieve an entity. You get an instance of your aggregate root, but if you follow the relationships, you also have all those other objects. It's perfectly logical that when you save an entity, all those other objects are saved too.

I don't know which technology you're using, but you should write your repository so that it does that.

also, why is the query side not allowed to use repositories ? Repositories are not only used to save data. They are also used to retrieve it. How are you retrieving objects without repositories (even if you don't modify them ?)